# Как лучше реорганизовать структуру БД?

Tags: sql, база-данных

На данный момент есть вот такая вот структура БД:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Основная сущность это таблица `Product`. Есть связанная с ней таблица `ProductDetail`, в которой должны храниться более детальная информация по продуктам. Вся беда в том, что эти продукты между собой достаточно сильно отличаются и поэтому в таблице `ProductDetail` появляется куча связанных c ней таблиц-справочников.
Как лучше реорганизовать данную структуру? Ибо то, что сейчас на картинке это лишь малая часть справочников, которые мы собираемся добавить. В дальнейшем их станет ещё больше...
Понимаю, что должно быть какое-то стандартное решение для моего случая, но не могу его найти.

Comment: Вообще, по-моему, структура со справочниками это хорошо: в случае добавления/удаления поля не придется переиначивать главную таблицу. И в целом нагляднее

Comment: @Matty тут речь похоже идет о том, что таблица свойств продукта предполагается будет расширяться, и каждое новое свойство будет тянуть новый справочник. И проблема, вероятно, будет в том, что не все свойства присущи каждому продукту. Какие-то будут обладать одними свойствами, а какие-то  другими. В таком случае такое подход действительно не лучший вариант, и с точки зрения описания предметной области само "свойство" продукта должно быт отдельной сущностью, а  не "полем" продукта.

Comment: @teran, лучше бы я и не описал всю проблему, но не могли бы вы пояснить что значит каждое свойство продукта должно быть не полем, а отдельной сущностью?

Comment: @МихаилКабаков подумайте над тем, что у с одной стороны должен быть перечень продуктов с минимальным набором свойств, как название, цена, описание, категория. и т.п С другой стороны должен быть перечень характеристик продукта, таких как цвет, длина, материал, то есть в принципе отдельная таблица характеристик. +добавить возможность связывания продукта с характеристиками в смысле "продукт обладает характеристикой", где свойством связи будет значение. Сюда можно прибавить некоторые наборы характеристик для групп товаров. То есть если продукт относится к категории, то наследует ее характеристики.

Answer (score 1):

В Product напрямую заносите id справочника связанного с этим продуктом.

Пока не вижу смысла в таблице ProductDetail

Answer (score 1):

Структура явно денормализована.

Из схемы видно, что Product хранит сведения и самОй сущности Продукт (код, наименование), и об отдельных экземплярах этой сущности (цены). Один и тот же по сути атрибут (название) хранится и в таблице Product (ProductName), и в таблице ProductDetail (ShortName). Это итог неправильного анализа предметной области или отсутствия такового. Рекомендую выполнить его (заново).

А что до словарей-справочников, то большое их количество Вас не должно смущать. Даже если всё свалить в одну таблицу, лучше не станет - какая разница, привязывать к основной таблице в запросе десять разных справочников или десять копий одного справочника?